# How to slice the dataset in Python in specific intervals

Tags: sorting, slice

I have a dataset with n rows, how can I access a specific number of rows every specific number of rows through the whole dataset using Python?

For example, in 100 rows data set and I want to access 10 rows every 10 rows, like 1:10, 20:30, 40:50, 60:70, 80:90

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of something like this

```
df.iloc[np.array([int(x/10) for x in df.index]) % 2 == 0]
```

It takes the index of the dataframe, divides it by 10 and casts it to an int. This basically just removes the last digit in this example.

With the modulo statement the first 10 rows are `True`, the next 10 `False` and so on. This is then used with iloc to get just the lines with the `True` value.

This requires a continuously increasing index. If for example some rows were already filtered out this is not the case. [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) can be used to reset the index.